# Why does webapp2 auth model use a unique table?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm implementing the webapp2 auth into my codebase and wanted to understand this quirk:

In [models.py](http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.py), I see that it states:

> To ensure property uniqueness when creating a new `User`, we first create
>       `Unique` records for those properties, and if everything goes well we can
>       save the new `User` record::

To me this seems like a very complicated way of testing for uniqueness and to be honest, I don't completely understand what the "create_multi" function is doing....which may be why I'm a little confused here. My thought process is:

> Just do a quick query to see if the username (auth.id) exists in the datastore. If not then put().

I know I'm missing something, can someone explain it to me? I have a hunch that maybe the code was entered in there so that it would be easy, if people wanted, to have multiple uniques?

thanks!

p.s. Apparently the webapp2 code was inspired by [this piece of coding](http://squeeville.com/2009/01/30/add-a-unique-constraint-to-google-app-engine/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have two unique values in that model: username and auth_id.

So, because all users don't belong to the same entity group, we can't check for uniqueness using transactions. And that's why the Unique model exists: to ensure uniqueness for those two properties.

I agree, it is a lot complicated. But how else would you do it? (honest question)

**Update:** more details on why uniqueness is checked that way.

There are only two ways to (safely) enforce a datastore unique constraint: transactions or using the entity key. Transactions are limited to up to 5 entity groups, and using the key you are limited to 1 unique property. If don't want to use the key (because, say, the property can be mutable, like an e-mail), or you *really* need more unique properties in the 
same kind, you need to create a specialized kind just for uniqueness checks. More or less what is done there in the link you posted.

Comment: hey, so in my application (granted, not the use case of all applications) the **email is the username and the auth_id**. 

So from that perspective, I was going to suggest simply doing a query for all auth_ids to see if any matched the new one inputted by the user.

Comment: Here's my thinking of why you're stressing transactions: if we don't use transactions, if two sign-ups try to register the same username at the same millisecond it could allow a duplicate if my method was used? Let me know if i'm on the right track. thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can't enforce uniqueness based solely on a query without transaction. I updated the answer to explain this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Initially I was skeptical because I figured it would be super inefficient, but the more I think about it: it's only really used when you create a user (on signups), so I guess unless you have a ton of signups (not a bad problem to have), it won't be too costly.

Comment: Yeah, it is a small price to pay to never worry about duplicated user ID's. :) Now, if this isn't asking too much, please accept the answer. :)